# Simple bitset in Go

Tags: go, bitset

I was playing with an implemention of sieve of Eratosthenes in Go and realised a memory-efficient solution would benefit from a memory-efficient data structure for storing boolean values at the given location - something like [bitset in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/).

I created this simple implementation which is backed by `map[int]byte`. Initial benchmarks show that it's significantly faster than using `map[int]bool` for the same purposes. Any feedback is welcome.

```
package bitset

import "errors"

// BitSet represents a set of booleans.
type BitSet struct {
    buckets map[int]byte
}

// New creates a new BitSet.
func New() *BitSet {
    return &BitSet{make(map[int]byte)}
}

// Set sets the bit at the given location to the given value. For example,
// bitset.Set(18, true) sets the bit at the position 18 to 1.
func (b *BitSet) Set(pos int, value bool) {
    if pos < 0 {
        panic(errors.New("index out of range"))
    }

    index := pos / 8
    bit := uint(pos % 8)
    current, ok := b.buckets[index]
    if value {
        current = current | (1 << bit)
    } else {
        current = current &^ (1 << bit)
    }
    if current != 0 {
        b.buckets[index] = current
    } else if ok {
        delete(b.buckets, index)
    }
}

// Get reads the bit value at the given position.
func (b *BitSet) Get(pos int) bool {
    if pos < 0 {
        panic(errors.New("index out of range"))
    }

    index := pos / 8
    bit := uint(pos % 8)
    if ((b.buckets[index] >> bit) & 1) == 1 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

// ToSlice returns a slice containing all the bit positions that are set to 1.
func (b *BitSet) ToSlice() (slice []int) {
    for index, value := range b.buckets {
        bit := 0
        for value > 0 {
            if (value & 1) == 1 {
                slice = append(slice, index*8+bit)
            }
            bit++
            value = value >> 1
        }
    }
    return slice
}
```

Benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkBitSet-4            100      17703207 ns/op      833918 B/op        492 allocs/op
BenchmarkMap-4                50      25846182 ns/op     3701760 B/op       3985 allocs/op
```

When both map and bitset are given the correct initial capacity:

```
BenchmarkBitSet-4            100      18789690 ns/op      605561 B/op        183 allocs/op
BenchmarkMap-4               100      23047036 ns/op     1856182 B/op       1676 allocs/op
```

Benchmark code (I'm aware there are refinements that can be applied, but I just went with a simple implementation, since the point was to test the bitset):

```
package bitset

import (
    "testing"
)

func generateSieveBitSet(max int) []int {
    bitset := New()
    for i := 2; i <= max; i++ {
        bitset.Set(i, true)
    }
    for candidate := 2; candidate <= max; candidate++ {
        if !bitset.Get(candidate) {
            continue
        }
        for notPrime := candidate * candidate; notPrime <= max; notPrime += candidate {
            bitset.Set(notPrime, false)
        }
    }
    return bitset.ToSlice()
}

func generateSieveMap(max int) []int {
    bitset := make(map[int]bool)
    for i := 2; i <= max; i++ {
        bitset[i] = true
    }
    for candidate := 2; candidate <= max; candidate++ {
        if !bitset[candidate] {
            continue
        }
        for notPrime := candidate * candidate; notPrime <= max; notPrime += candidate {
            delete(bitset, notPrime)
        }
    }
    primes := make([]int, 0, len(bitset))
    for prime := range bitset {
        primes = append(primes, prime)
    }
    return primes
}

func BenchmarkBitSet(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        generateSieveBitSet(100000)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMap(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        generateSieveMap(100000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes using this code ?

Comment: You are making unsubstantiated performance claims. Where are your benchmarks?

Comment: Good point, added benchmark code that uses a sieve and results.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is really nice, however you could get way better performance with an array of bool!

generateSieve with a **`[]bool`**:

```
func generateSieveArray(max int) []int {
    array := make([]bool, max+1)
    for i := 2; i <= max; i++ {
        array[i] = true
    }

    for candidate := 2; candidate <= max; candidate++ {
        if !array[candidate] {
            continue
        }
        for notPrime := candidate * candidate; notPrime <= max; notPrime += candidate {
            array[notPrime] = false
        }
    }
    result := make([]int, 0)
    for i, v := range array {
        if v {
            result = append(result, i)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func BenchmarkArray(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        generateSieveArray(100000)
    }
}
```

and here is the result:

```
BenchmarkBitSet-2             50          33380755 ns/op          833430 B/op        487 allocs/op
BenchmarkMap-2                50          34550383 ns/op         3699287 B/op       3983 allocs/op
BenchmarkArray-2            2000            915800 ns/op          492792 B/op         21 allocs/op
```

Almost **two order of magnitude** faster ! And the code is way easier to understand

Also added a small test to make sure that all `generateSieve` implementations have the same output:

```
func TestSieveResult(t *testing.T) {
    nb := 100000
    result := generateSieveBitSet(nb)
    mapResult := generateSieveMap(nb)
    arrayResult := generateSieveArray(nb)

    l := [][]int{result, mapResult, arrayResult}
    for _, s := range l {
        sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
            return s[i] < s[j]
        })
    }

    for i, v := range result {
        if v != mapResult[i] || v != arrayResult[i] {
            t.Fail()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - it seems that a bool slice trumps over even a modified bitset implementation that uses a byte slice. That said, I was looking more for tips on how to improve my code rather than how to write an efficient sieve - if you have any tips, it'd be appreciated.